# Why does negative lookback work this way in regex?

Tags: regex

The regex `((?!hede).)*$` matches `sasha hede`, it matched the part `ede`, which makes sense to me. But the regex `^((?!hede).)*` only matches `sasha<space>`, I expected it to match `sasha hed`. What am I missing ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat

Comment: There are some regex engine optimizations when using anchors `^ or $`. The overall result is that given `$`, the position _starts_ there and decrements as far as possible to match. Same with `^` except it starts there, then increments its position as far as possible. That's the basic reason for the difference. And fwiw, the construct here is a _negative look ahead_ (not lookback).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part...

```
((?!hede).)*
```

... is read as 'match any number of symbols, **each** of those is not a start of `hede` sequence'. In other words, you set up a rule that should be matched by each character in the matched substring.

In `sasha hede`, only `s`, `a`, `s`, `h`, `a`, and  (whitespace) characters match the description. However, `h` symbol doesn't (it starts a `hede` sequence), so matching has to be stopped here.

BTW, it's the same with the first pattern (bound to the end of string): matching is stopped at the very first symbol excluded by the pattern. If it were not the case, the whole string would have been matched, not just `ede`.